# How to use AutoMapper for related structures in .NET 6 Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, automapper

I am trying to implement AutoMapper to my project. It functions properly by using the DTOs within the services. I am able to implement AutoMapper to simple DTOs, however I have no clue how to implement it to a DTO which navigates through multiple entities over their relationships. Bear with me while I explain the relationships:

I have an `Artist` entity. This artist may play in a band and it is connected to the `Band` entity through a `Role` table. In the `Role` table, we have the artist and band entities and the instruments played by the artist in that specific band is stored in a table called `RoleInstruments`. I have a DTO called `ArtistRoleDto` which I use for multiple purposes. This DTO has Artist, Band and Instrument information. Sometimes I use it to find multiple artists playing in a single band, sometimes I use it to find multiple roles (which instrument played in which band) by the same artist.

The variety of the use cases confuses me and I have no clue how to navigate through necessary relationship tables while defining the mapper.

This is the code that I wish to complete.

```
CreateMap<ArtistRoleDto, Artist>()
                .ForMember(
                    dest => dest.Id,
                    opt => opt.MapFrom(src => $"{src.ArtistId}")
                    )
                .ForMember(
                    dest => dest.FirstName,
                    opt => opt.MapFrom(src => $"{src.FirstName}")
                    )
                .ForMember(
                    dest => dest.LastName,
                    opt => opt.MapFrom(src => $"{src.LastName}")
                    )
                .ForMember(
                    dest => dest.Genre,
                    opt => opt.MapFrom(src => $"{src.ArtistGenre}")
                    )
                .ForMember(
                    // BandId - through Roles
                    )
                .ForMember(
                    // BandName - through Roles.Band
                    )
                .ForMember(
                    // BandGenre - through Roles.Band
                    )
                .ForMember(
                    // Instrument - through Roles.RoleInstruments (both lists)
                    );
```

Here are the definitions for the related entities:

```
public class Artist
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Genre { get; set; }
    public string? Description { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}

public class Role
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // Foreign Key to Artist Table
    public int ArtistId { get; set; }
    public Artist Artist { get; set; }

    // Foreign Key to Band Table
    public int BandId { get; set; }
    public Band Band { get; set; }

    // Additional properties related to the role, e.g., RoleDescription
    public string? Description { get; set; }

    // Collection of RoleInstruments associated with the role
    public ICollection<RoleInstruments> RoleInstruments { get; set; }
}

public class RoleInstruments
{
    // Foreign Key to Role Table
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public Role Role { get; set; }

    // Foreign Key to Instrument Table
    public int InstrumentId { get; set; }
    public Instrument Instrument { get; set; }
}
```

I tried different approaches but honestly I feel clueless. First thing that came to my mind was:

```
            .ForMember(
                dest => dest.Roles.Select(r => r.BandId),
                opt => opt.MapFrom(src => $"{src.BandId}")
                )
            .ForMember(
                // BandName - through Roles.Band
                dest => dest.Roles.Select(r => r.Band.Name),
                opt => opt.MapFrom(src => $"{src.BandName}")
                )
            .ForMember(
                // BandGenre - through Roles.Band
                dest => dest.Roles.Select(r => r.Band.Genre),
                opt => opt.MapFrom(src => $"{src.BandGenre}")
                )
            .ForMember(
                // Instrument - Through Roles.RoleInstruments (both lists)
                dest => dest.Roles.SelectMany(r => r.RoleInstruments.Select(ri => ri.Instrument.Name),
                opt => opt.MapFrom(src => $"{src.Instrument}")
                ));
```

Then I tried a few recommendations from my beloved ChatGPT, the closest I got was:

```
.ForMember(
    dest => dest.Roles,
    opt => opt.MapFrom(src => new List<Role>
    {
        new Role
        {
            BandId = src.BandId,
            Band = new Band
            {
                Name = src.BandName,
                Genre = src.BandGenre
            },
            RoleInstruments = src.Instrument.Split(", ").Select(instrumentName => new RoleInstruments
            {
                Instrument = new Instrument
                {
                 // Here I get an error saying I can't convert char (instrumentName) to str.
                    Name = instrumentName 
                }
            }).ToList()
```

So I now think maybe the solution might include creating a new `Role` within the profile?
Or considering that the ArtistRoleDto is being used in various contexts, maybe I should define it different mappers in different profiles? When using it in a band service I may use it as it is defined in BandProfile?

I'm thankful to everyone who took the time to look into the issue.

Comment: What ChatGPT won't tell you is that some times it's easier to manually map it!

Comment: @GHDevOps haha it definitely is yet I'm actually developing this project to learn more about .NET Core in general, being guided by a mentor in my internship. They recommended me to study AutoMapper so here I am.

Comment: To solve the `instrumentName` error just call `ToString()` on `instrumentName`:

`Name = instrumentName.ToString();`

Comment: What usually helps is to write the projection without AutoMapper first. It's all but clear how you're going to reduce collections into only one string. Which band provides BandName, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

So the solution to this problem was actually mapping this specific object manually, as recommended in the comments to the question. This was because the relationships were too complicated to hassle with AutoMapper for. However when faced a similar problem with AutoMapper, I found out that all I had to do to not face issues when moving through relationships was including the properties when defining the object to be mapped in the service. For example:

```
public async Task<List<RoleInBandDto>> GetRoles(int bandId)
{
    var roleInstruments = await _context.RoleInstruments
       .Where(ri => ri.Role.Band.Id == bandId)
       .Include(ri => ri.Instrument)
       .Include(ri => ri.Role).ThenInclude(r => r.Artist)
       .Include(ri => ri.Role).ThenInclude(r => r.Band).ToListAsync();
    var roles = _mapper.Map<List<RoleInBandDto>>(roleInstruments);

    return roles;
}
```

I made sure to include all the tables that AutoMapper would have to navigate through which was defined here:

```
CreateMap<RoleInstruments, RoleInBandDto>()
    .ForMember(
        dest => dest.BandName,
        opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Role.Band.Name))
    .ForMember(
        dest => dest.ArtistFirstName,
        opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Role.Artist.FirstName))
    .ForMember(
        dest => dest.ArtistLastName,
        opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Role.Artist.LastName))
    .ForMember(
        dest => dest.Instrument,
        opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Role.RoleInstruments.Select(ri => ri.Instrument.Name)));
```

Comment: Check [`ProjectTo`](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html) and [`IncludeMembers`](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Flattening.html#includemembers).